# Проблемы с обновлением состояния в моем кастомном CheckDelegate в QML ListView

Tags: qt, qml, controls, qtquick

Вопрос: "Я работаю над приложением на Qt QML, где используется QML ListView с ButtonGroup и кастомным CheckDelegate. Но у меня возникла проблема с обновлением состояния в моем кастомном CheckDelegate при выборе элементов. Я взял реализацию из официальной документации Qt (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-checkbox.html), но что-то идет не так.

Вот часть моего кода:

```
ListView {
    height: contentHeight
    anchors {
        top: _zeroingTitle.bottom
        topMargin: 12
        left: parent.left
        leftMargin: 40
        right: parent.right
        rightMargin: 40
    }
    spacing: 12

    ButtonGroup {
        id: _zeroingCheckGroup
        exclusive: false
        checkState: _zeroingCheckBasic.checkState
    }

    header: CheckDelegate {
        id: _zeroingCheckBasic
        width: parent.width
        height: 72
        padding: 0

        text: "Выбрать всё"

        checkState: _zeroingCheckGroup.checkState
    }

    model: JointsModel {}
    delegate: CheckDelegate {
        width: parent.width
        height: 72
        padding: 0

        text: model.name

        ButtonGroup.group: _zeroingCheckGroup
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что состояние моего кастомного CheckDelegate не обновляется при выборе элементов в _zeroingCheckBasic. Как я могу исправить это и сделать работу моего CheckDelegate корректной? Был бы благодарен за пример решения этой проблемы."

---

Проблема исчезает если я описываю общий делегат вне header.